# Is a geodesic an Isometry?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, geodesic, isometry, complete-spaces

If we consider a geodesic $c: [a,b]\to M$ as a map
$$f:\begin{cases} M\to M \\ c(a)\mapsto c(b)\end{cases}$$
is it true that the so defined map is an isometry?

To give some context:

A Riemannian manifold is said to be *homogenous*, if for any two points $p,q\in M$ there is an isometry $f\in \operatorname{Iso}(M)$ such that $f(p)=q$.

*Propositon*: If a Riemannian manifold is homogenous, it is geodesically complete.

Proof: If we take a normal neighbourhood (i.e. one for which there is an $\epsilon>0$ such that exponential map $\exp_p:B(0,\epsilon)\to M$ is diffeomorphic onto its image), since we can connect any two points by isometries, it follows that the same $\epsilon$ holds for all $p\in M$. In particular this enables us to extend the intervall of definition of any geodesic to all of $\mathbb{R}$ and thus $M$ is geodesically complete.

I was now wondering if the converse is also true, meaning that if we have a geodesically complete manifold, in particular we can connect any two points on a manifold by a geodesic, which if geodesics where isometries would imply that a complete manifold is homogenous.

Comment: ups, yeah, sorry; changed one of the two..

Comment: This map is not well defined. Note that $c|_{[a,b/2]}:[a,b/2]\to M$ is also a geodesic. So which value does $c(a)$ map to? $c(b)$ or $c(b/2)$?

Comment: @user2520938 So am I getting you right, that there is no way to actually make sense of the sentence "A geodesic is a isometry connecting points?"

Comment: Fixing a point the (time 1) exponential map is a map from the tangent space at that point to the manifold obtained by following a geodesic with a given start velocity. In general it is an isometry only along the geodesic.

Comment: @H.H.Rugh Oh, I see, so the answer to my previous comment is no, since from existance and uniqueness of geodesics it follows that using proper initial conditions i have a well defined map as wanted using the exponential map.. Am I right that it thus is only left to show that the exponential map is an isometry? Do you know how to do so?

Comment: As the tangent space is flat (zero curvature) in general the exponential map can not be isometric (if $M$ has non-zero curvature). But there are other interesting properties. You may look in: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_space

Comment: @H.H.Rugh Thank you for your answer. We know from the Cartan-Hadamard Theorem that for a simply connected, complete Riemannian manifold with everywhere negative sectional curvature the exponential map is a diffeomorphism from $T_pM\to M$. I know that $\mathbb{R}^n\simeq T_pM$ and that $\mathbb{R}^n$ is flat, but what speficifly goes wrong when trying to pull back the metric from $M$ via that diffeomorphism? This question came up since I'm indeed talking about a complete Riemannian manifold when regarding my question.. Thanks alot for your help!

Comment: I don't really have any intuition for how it goes wrong. But curvatures are (magically) preserved uner isometries so in general you can not hope for an isometry. (you may google for 'isometry and curvature')

Comment: @H.H.Rugh Yeah, right. Thank you very much! If you don't mind you can add your comments as a answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixing a point the (time 1) exponential map is a map from the tangent space at that point to the manifold obtained by following a geodesic with a given start velocity. In general it is an isometry only along the geodesic.

As the tangent space is flat (zero curvature) in general the exponential map can not be isometric (if M has non-zero curvature). But there are other interesting properties. You may look in: [Symmetric space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_space)

I don't really have any intuition for how it goes wrong. But curvatures are (magically) preserved under isometries so in general you can not hope for an isometry. (you may google for 'isometry and curvature')